# Some comments have been made about me in the exit interviews of people in my department, Do I have right to see them

Tags: human-resources

I have been made aware of some comments made about me in exit interviews by people who worked in my department.  HR have not forwarded them to me, but spoken with my line manager.  She has not told me about the comments or discussed them with me.  So I kind of feel like I am being judged without the opportunity to a) know what has been said and b) to put my version of events either. These comments also relate to managers I manage, so I want to know if there are any issues with how my managers are managing others, so I can deal with it.

Do I have a right to see them?  I have asked verbally and by email for the comments to be forwarded to me.  But so far this has been ignored and frankly not even had the pleasure of an acknowledgement of my request.

Comment: This will depend on your company policy.

Comment: I would at least *ask* to see them. When they ask why, you say something along the lines of because you want to grow as a person and welcome all constructive criticism.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say I am in the UK

Comment: How and in what context were you made aware of these comments?

Comment: "Do I have a right" isn't a question we can answer; that depends on company policy, local law, and maybe other stuff.  If your question is really "how can I get access to this feedback", that's a question that would fit the site.  I'm putting this on hold; if that's what you meant, please [edit] and we can review for reopening.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

> Do I have a right to see them?

In one company, prior to my exit interview, I specifically asked who would be allowed to see the notes the HR rep was making. I asked if I mentioned individuals, would they read my comments.

Her answer was "No". The comments were for her and wouldn't be shared with the individuals. They would be summarized, and the overall thoughts and tone might be shared with relevant managers. If a pattern of problems were detected with individuals, the appropriate managers would be notified, and a discussion could take place. But I was assured that my specific comments would not be shared with the named individuals, and the summaries would not have my name attached to them.

These things tend to be locale-specific (and perhaps company-specific). If some comments have been made about you during exit interviews that have led to repercussions, you should call or walk over and talk with HR to find out what specific rights you may or may not have here. The HR reps will almost certainly know what is permitted and what is not.

If you are simply trying to get a general sense of the issues and tone (without needing to see the verbatim comments), HR can almost certainly provide that for you. Rather than just asking that the comments be forwarded, ask if you can have a meeting to understand the issues being conveyed.

Comment: This question is part of this week's [Broken Windows For Review](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2960/broken-windows-for-review-week-4) on meta.